# SOQL to get list of users related to a specific parent account

Tags: soql

I'm trying to create a query that will fetch all the users that are associated to the parent account of an specific account. Both accounts are `PersonAccount` entities.

So, basically I only have the "child account" value, and I need to query the parent and then fetch all the users that have the ContactId associated to the contactId of the parent.

So far I have tried this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, ContactId, Contact.AccountId 
FROM User
WHERE ContactId != NULL AND ContactId IN
    (SELECT Parent.PersonContactId FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name = 'RECORD_NAME' AND Id = '...')
```

This query throws *The inner select field 'Parent.PersonContactId' cannot have more than one level of relationships*

So, I tried this one here:

```
SELECT Id, Contact.Name, Contact.AccountId
FROM User
WHERE Contact.AccountId IN 
    (SELECT ParentId FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name = 'RECORD_NAME' AND Id = '...')
```

But the error now became *The left operand 'Contact.AccountId' cannot have more than one level of relationships*

How can I obtain that information with a single query?, Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AccountId on the User object should be the same as the Contact.AccountId.
see - [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm#:~:text=ID%20of%20the%20Account%20associated%20with%20a%20Customer%20Portal%20user](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm#:%7E:text=ID%20of%20the%20Account%20associated%20with%20a%20Customer%20Portal%20user).
(Note the field is not updateable, it is updated when the ContactId field is updated).

So you can just use

```
SELECT Id, Contact.Name, Contact.AccountId
FROM User
WHERE AccountId IN 
    (SELECT ParentId FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name = 'RECORD_NAME' AND Id = '...')
```

Though I would suggest you might want to filter out any of the users that have a NULL AccountId, and where the Account does NOT have a ParentId